# checking params after navigation do nothing at all

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am passing params with navigation like this:

```
 this.props.navigation.navigate('main', { status: "done" });
```

as shown I am navigating  to main and passing params called status and in main screen I am doing something like this:

```
const main = ({ route, navigation }) => {

// some line of code here 
     useEffect(() => {
    
            if (route.params?.status) {
                setTakingPic(true);
            }
    
        }, [route.params?.status]);

/* the rest of code */
```

so I am checking if there any params called `status` passed then `setTakingPic(true)` which will open camera but what actually happened is nothing and camera not opened but when I press `Ctrl + S` on the same page the camera opened. any help please.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to run only first time then remove the use effect dependency

```
const main = ({ route, navigation }) => {

    // some line of code here 
         useEffect(() => {
        
                if (route.params?.status) {
                    setTakingPic(true);
                }
        
            }, []);
    
    /* the rest of code */
```

Comment: no i am actually navigating to previous screen which i have to use effect dependency